# ¿La ejecución de un trigger en mysql está asegurada?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Suponemos una tabla *ingresos* sobre la que queremos mantener un registro de operaciones (un log sobre las acciones `INSERT` y `UPDATE`). El sistema de base de datos es MySQL.

Para hacer este log se opta por generar triggers sobre la tabla en la que estamos trabajando, en este caso *ingresos*.

**Mis dudas son las siguientes:**

- En caso de querer hacer una posterior auditoría, ¿cuál sería la mejor opción?, ¿generar el trigger indicando que el log se haga `BEFORE {ACCIÓN}` o `AFTER {ACCIÓN}`?
- ¿La ejecución del trigger se realiza de forma atómica en relación a la acción sobre la tabla?

Con esto último quiero decir lo siguiente:

Suponiendo que generemos el trigger con con `AFTER {ACCIÓN}` ¿Podría ocurrir que se genere el `insert` o el `update` y a causa de un fallo posterior (error al reservar memoria, kernel panic...) no se ejecutase el `insert` sobre la tabla de log?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te respondo en un resumen y luego busco los enlaces y referencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Información general sobre iniciadores y su sintaxis en MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

**En caso de querer hacer una posterior auditoría, ¿cuál sería la mejor opción?, ¿generar el trigger indicando que el log se haga `BEFORE {ACCIÓN}` o `AFTER {ACCIÓN}`?**

Para temas relacionados con auditorías de cambios es mejor usar `AFTER {ACCIÓN}` para tener disponibles los valores finales que han sido escritos en la base de datos y que se ejecute únicamente cuando se ha escrito, borrado o actualizado de manera efectiva el registro en la base de datos.

Durante la fase de `BEFORE {ACCIÓN}` aún no se han resuelto los valores por defecto y, además, podría darse el caso de que otro disparador `BEFORE {ACCIÓN}` cancele la inserción, dejando en la auditoría un registro de `{ACCIÓN}` que no fue llevado a cabo finalmente y no hay manera de marcarlo como tal (quizá una solución podría ser un `BEFORE` que ponga un campo `definitivo` a 0 y hacer que en el `AFTER` se ponga a 1).

**¿La ejecución del trigger se realiza de forma atómica en relación a la acción sobre la tabla?**

Sí. El disparador se podría considerar como parte de una misma transacción. O se hace todo o no se hace nada.

Ejemplo:

Si falla la inserción de datos en la tabla de auditorías por (por poner un ejemplo) restricciones de clave, se cancelaría la inserción del registro original.

Como resultado de fallar la inserción dentro del trigger se provoca un `rollback` de la inserción original, por lo que puedes estar seguro que no perderás ningún registro.

A nivel práctico fallaría la consulta SQL original, aunque con un mensaje confuso porque no tendría relación con la consulta SQL enviada, si no con la generada en el iniciador.

---

PD: Hay que recordar que las modificaciones hechas por actualizaciones en cascada de claves foráneas no son interceptadas por los iniciadores ([ver documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)):

> **NOTE:** Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers

Comment: Muchas gracias!